# If I buy a used computer with Windows 8 can I do a fresh install of Windows 10 without having to buy a Windows 10 license?

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, product-key, product-key-recovery

If I buy a used computer with Windows 8 can I do a fresh install of Windows 10 for free?

This would be different from an upgrade in that the fresh install would remove whatever had been on there before.

Comment: The Free Upgrade to W10 is long over, you will have to buy a W10 license to activate it after installation.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do so, but you also might not.

According to Dr. Philip Yip (Dell Community Rockstar and Microsoft Windows Insider MVP):

> "Windows 7 and Windows 8 keys still act as Windows 10 Keys and I recommend migrating to the latest build of Windows 10.."

[Dr. Philip Yip: The Unofficial Windows 10 Reinstallation Guide: Windows 10](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/windows-10/)

And also:

> "The 25 digit System Locked Preinstallation (SLP) Product Key resides with a Microsoft Digital Marker (MSDM) Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI) table embedded in the Unified Extensive Firmware Interface (UEFI) BIOS."

[Dr. Philip Yip: The Unofficial Windows 10 Reinstallation Guide: The OEM Product Key and OEM System Locked Preinstallation](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/the-oem-product-key-and-oem-system-locked-preinstallation/)

So in theory all you would need to do is get the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), run it, install the Windows 10 installation system onto a USB flash drive with more than 5 GB, (it needs to use the whole flash drive), and then boot from the USB flash drive. In theory the whole process would take maybe about two or three hours and could be done for the most part unattended.

If you don't have a USB flash drive using a DVD is another option.

But there could be two issues:

1) The device might not have the product key in the ACPI table. As Yip's page says:

> No MSDM table = No UEFI BIOS Embedded OEM SLP Key:

[Dr. Philip Yip: The Unofficial Windows 10 Reinstallation Guide: The OEM Product Key and OEM System Locked Preinstallation](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/the-oem-product-key-and-oem-system-locked-preinstallation/)

So then, as far I know, you would need to buy another license.

2) In my experience even if the device does have the product key in the ACPI table it still could not work. Maybe there could be some issue with the license being an educational one and so then it's not enabled for that case.

The difference in cost between a used machine with Windows 10 and a machine with Windows 8 will not necessarily be that much anyway.

Comment: You can install W10 but it will not activate unless it has a Digital Entitlement, which i most likely dies not.